# ODBC cannot open MS Access database whose password contains '{'

Tags: python, ms-access, odbc, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to password protected Access Databases with pyodbc. The passwords are created based on the filename and may contain special characters. I've made sure the connection string is correct before calling the .connect() method.

```
import pyodbc
conn_str = r"DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\user\PW issue\test.accdb;PWD=abc{123"
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
```

I'm getting the following error (shortened version - it only repeats itself from the '"[HY000]' part 2 more times:

> Error: ('HY000', "[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access
> Driver]General error Unable to open registry key Temporary (volatile)
> Ace DSN for process 0x5f80 Thread 0x5a54 DBC 0x96f3be58
> Jet'. (63) (SQLDriverConnect)")

I've tried to make sense of many sources such as tens of similar posts here, and also other places, for example:
https://www.connectionstrings.com/formating-rules-for-connection-strings/

From what I can tell the issue could be how the driver interprets the connection string, not how I am structuring it in python.
The two characters that I'm sure cause an issue on their own are "{" and "%". I mainly tried to focus on solving the issue with a file that only had "{" in it.
The connection string works properly for any password that doesn't contain these 2.

Creating different passwords is not an option.

An example password would be: "abc{123"
What I've tried already within the connection string:

1. "...;{PWD=abc{123}"
2. "...;'PWD=abc{123'"
3. "...;PWD=abc{{123"
4. "...;PWD=abc'{123"
5. "...;PWD={abc'{123}"
6. "...;PWD={abc{{123}"
   I've probably tried some other combinations too. As one source said to escape "{"s with doubling it, while the other source said the whole password has to be escaped with {}. Then again others said to enclose the password in single quotes, and another said to escape the special character with a single quote. So out of desperation I tried their combinations.

Comment: It is a known issue/limitation which has been reported to Microsoft. I've seen it when assigning a GUID as the password; `PWD=9AEBA205-2BC6-40B2-8982-9AFFC15C5879` will work, while `PWD={9AEBA205-2BC6-40B2-8982-9AFFC15C5879}` will fail.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have encountered a deficiency in the MS Access ODBC driver. When using other ODBC drivers like "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server", an open curly bracket in a password is not a problem unless it is the first character of the password. So, for logging in to SQL Server

```
UID=john;PWD=abc{123;
```

works just fine. If John's password was `{abc` then he would have to use

```
UID=john;PWD={{abc};
```

Furthermore, the MS Access OLEDB provider can open a database whose password is `abc{123`

```vb
connStr = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\Users\Public\zzz_test.accdb;" & _
    "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=abc{123;"
```

so this is an issue with the Access ODBC driver.